# Removing one-to-many relations using splice

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm having some trouble getting relation deletion to work exactly how I would expect it to.

For example I have two simple tables, `users` and `permissions` with a one-to-many relation between users and permissions (or it could be many-to-many in this example as well).

I first tried deleting one of the related permissions using `userDatasource.deleteItem()` or `userDatasource.item.permissions[index]._delete()` but when you use either of those functions it marks the record as deleted client side so you run into trouble when you need to insert again.

I then found a related question that said to use `item.relation.splice(startIndex, 1)` to just break the relation and that worked as expected but now I have a bunch of extra rows in my database with the `user` foreign key null.  I would much rather have the same behavior as `.splice` but also have it delete those records from the database.  Is there any way to do that or is App Maker supposed to detect the broken relation and automatically delete the row from the table?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a check after the splice like this:

```
if (item.relation.length === 0) {
  item._delete();
}
```